# running unit tests within a host application in .net

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, autocad

Im developing an addin for AutoCAD to process DWGs. Now, i would like to run unit tests for my code.

The problem is that i cannot load the autocad api without having a running instance of autocad console. My DLL has a custom entry point method, so the question is how to execute my unit tests from that method (and ideally get my results back to visual studio). 
Do any of the unit test frameworks (VS, NUnit (with Resharper)) give me any possibility to customize the way the test runner is executed?

that means setting a custom executable to run and starting my unit tests programmatically

```
public void MyEntryPoint()
{
   run_unit_tests();
}
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207289/nunit-api-and-running-tests-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

As part of VS2012, you now have the ability of create custom test runners to work with VS2012 chrome, I am aware that xunit and nunit have customer runners, which plugin to VS2012 test runner, you should be able to add write your own runner, you can have alook at the code in the xunit project [here](http://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx)