# Best Approach for dynamic Unit testing in generated C# classes

Tags: c#, nunit, code-generation

I am working on unit testing a code generator.  A unit test's basic flow is:

1. The Unit Test calls the appropriate method and code is generated. Easy enough.
2. The Unit Test compiles the generated c# code (of step #1). If code compliles, proceed to step 3, else stop everything.
3. If step#2 suceeded, the Unit Test then runs other, pre-written unit tests on the generated compiled code of step 2. For this I will utilize the solution described here: [Running individual NUnit tests programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980724/running-individual-nunit-tests-programmatically) and [NUnit API And Running Tests Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207289/nunit-api-and-running-tests-programmatically) .

The approach for step #2 is what this question is about: I am thinking I have two options (1) Run Visual Studio Command Line to compile the solution  Or (2) use 
CSharpCodeProvider with CompilerParameters. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much do you care that compilation is tied to VS? Should I be able to run the tests without VS installed?

Comment: You could have a look at Roslyn. It's the new c# compiler which has an API you can use: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Mike z, I do not really care if compilation of tied to VS.  I see where you are going with this:  If compilation needs to be tied to VS, then go with  CSharpCodeProvider.  But can CSharpCodeProvider/CompilerParameters offer everything that the VS command line offers?

Comment: Kenneth, I had taken a look at Roslyn, it just seemed a little too much for what I want to do...

Comment: What is the extent of the code that is being generated by each test method ? Are we talking about a single file or multiple interrelated files ?

Comment: @PhilGref this is an ORM project that has been in use for quite some time now.  The code generated is one c# class for each database table.  The c# classes are generated and  save to disk in a different assembly / c# project.  The unit tests use a sample database  of 5 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use Roslyn on a daily basis, and so I was tempted to go with Kenneth and recommend it, but, in your case, if the only information you want to know is if the code compiled, I would lean more towards the `CSharpCodeProvider` class, especially if each method that is being unit tested generates a single file of code. If you would have to to any kind of analysis on the generated code or if you , it might be worth using Roslyn, but I doubt this is your case. The only other pro Roslyn might bring you is that you can [open up a whole project/solution](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/) directly instead of trying to compile every separate file, which might appeal to you (it's a lot simpler to use than you might think).

Besides this advice, all I can say is that if you just have to choose between `CSharpCodeProvider` and the Command Line option, I would definitely go with the `CSharpCodeProvider`, since it already wraps and exposes the data and operations relevant to you analysis (Are there any errors ? => let's check if `compiledResults.Errors.Count == 0`). You don't need to call an external process (the C# compiler) in order to get what you want, which makes it a much simpler option in my opinion, while also having a lot of flexibility (i.e. The `CompilerParameters`)

I don't know if you have started playing around with it, but you shouldn't have too many problems with this method. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you.  I am going with Roslyn due to the ablity to open up a whole project/solution and compile it.  I did not know this.  Thanks again

Comment: Sure thing. Just keep the CSharpCodeProvider option open if Roslyn doesn't work out for some reason, I think that it's still the second best option.